# luque rod from spinal fusion might be acting like a human EMF antenna

Tags: antenna, electromagnetic, emf, electrostatic, human-signal

In 1994, I had a spinal fusion surgery to correct Scoliosis which was a result of my medical condition, Spinal Muscular Atrophy Type II.  I've used a wheelchair my entire life.  Because my upper body muscles could not hold up my spine, my spine developed an "S" curve (Scoliosis) as a result.  Below is a picture of the luque rod that is drilled into both sides of my pelvis and runs all the way up to vertebrae T3.  This prevented my Scoliosis from progressing when I was 13.
The cumulative curvature was 72 degrees before surgery and 11 degrees after the spinal fusion surgery.

[image]

For many years now, my body always gets very energized when I'm at large events with large numbers of people.  I lose my voice within the first 5 minutes I'm in a large crowd, but I feel great during the event and hours afterwards.  For a long time, I thought I felt this way from sound waves (music) because it only happened at concerts and weddings.  But then I started attending football and baseball games in my mid 20s.  And it also happened when no music was present, so it "clicked".  This was NOT from sound waves!  This was being caused by the energy from people, not from the music!  I can reproduce if I simply go to a movie.  I might be an outlier because my SMA causes my neurology to be extra sensitive.  For example, I can feel my Air Conditioner will turn on a 1/2 second before it turns on and I often wake up a split second before my alarm goes off on my smartphone.

The day after the Trump impeachment trial came to an end and the economy boomed, I felt great for weeks!  So that shows that people's energy were making me feel fantastic.  Whether that was good energy (happy) or bad energy (angry), it made my body feel great regardless.  And normally in the winter, I don't feel the greatest.  I live in Wisconsin.

Now the opposite effect is happening during this Coronavirus.  I don't feel very well and it's almost like my vagus nerve shut off temporarily to protect my body from the stress.  I live in a large condo building and everyone have been sitting at home now for 3 1/2 weeks stationary.  My heart beats irregularly in the mornings (I'm suspecting when people wake up and have high energy) and I can't "go" very well.  I have proof that this all started on the day people started having stress from the pandemic in on 3/13--I had a bad headache on that Friday.  And I'm not a person who panics about things really, but I can feel the negative energy of others now very much.  And I've never had a headache in my life!  I'm hoping I can talk to a gifted electrical engineer on here that can help figure this out.  I'm wondering how I can mimic human EMF and see if I can reverse what's going on or at least neutralize it.  Maybe we can offset the frequencies or override them?  I bought two different EMF meters to measure ultra low frequencies (near and around 7.83 Hz) and the 50-70 MHz ranges--which I'm finding humans give off.  I also bought a signal generator this week, but I have no idea how to use it.  And I bought a Tesla coil to neutralize EMF, but that doesn't seem to be helping much.  I'm willing to give you my phone number and we can figure it out together.  I'm not being crazy.  This is real.  I'm thinking my Harrington rod is acting as an antenna and amplifying the effects of what other are feeling.  If someone might be able to explain what is going on here with Bioelectromagnetics, I'm willing to listen and try any ideas you might have to correct what could be called a stress induced antenna.  Whether it's my rod or not, how could I realistically measure what's going on?

Comment: This site is not for discussions like this, the question is closed. I'm clearing the comments and please refrain from calling people out. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At 7 Hertz, the coupling will be almost totally electric field.

If your nervous system has impulses (sequences of neural firings) similar to others
around you, then you may be able to synchronize.

Systems that implement correlation are a strongly preferred means of communication in the presence of noise (random) and interference (may be determinist, as long as has weak
correlation with the desired signal).

Lets compute the coupling between two salty conductors, each 1 meter by 1 meter, located 1 meter apart, with a 1 millivolt difference.

In other words, how many electrons might one person's body be able to move from dorsal to ventral surfaces (sounds more scientific, eh) of another person standing 1 meter apart?

For simplicity, we'll use the parallel-plate capacitive model instead of round wire model.

C = Eo * Er * area / distance

we'll assume air insulation, and round off some constants, to find

C = 9e-12 farad/meter * area/distance

and area/distance == (1meter * 1meter)/1 meter === 1meter, so substitute

C = 9e-12farad/meter * 1 meter = 9 e-12 = 9 picofarads

Now using Q = C * V, we simply multiply C * V

9e-12 * 1 millivolt == 9e-15 coulombs

Since a "coulomb" (George Coulomb, a name to drop at parties) is 6.2e+18 electrons, we can compute the # of electrons induced in your body (not all of them heading to your spine)

## electrons == 9e-15 * 6e+18 == 72e+3 == 72,000 electrons

[ ahheeeem 9 * 6 = 54, but with all the assumptions used, its still fine ]

How strong is the signal, compared to the chemical noise?

Going out on a limb here:

We'll assume a correlation time of 100 seconds for your body to respond to an outside signal. Knowing the thermal noise floor (physics applies here) is

K * T

or 4.0e-21 watts/Hertz at 290 degree Kelvin, we'll lower the noise by 100X because of the 100 second correlation time, to the rather small

4e-23 watts

If you can show those electrons can produce that much or more signal power in your body, then your concept begins to be very interesting. This would be a Unity ratio of Signal/Noise, which using Logarithms becomes 0; we honor Alex Bell by multiplying by 10 (we still get zero) and append the scientific term "dB" to produce " 0 dB SNR ". People will flock to you, and venture capitalists' ears will perk up, should you speak of SNR.

We need the voltage and the current of the signal, to compute power.

We'll assume the voltage gradient across your body is 1 millivolt.
This may be way wrong, but we acknowledge this is a SWAG, depending on how charge flows (those 72,000 electrons, or maybe 54,000) thru your body and then out through your shoes (or wheelchair tire insulation) to the concrete floor.

We have the current: 72,000 electrons flowing 7 times a second. So what?

Wre know our current is 72,000 / 6e+18 = 7e+4/6e+18 == 1.2e-14 amps

our power I s V * I = 0.001volts * 1.2e-14 (lotta pretend precise math here)

Power = V * I = 1e-17 watts, which is factor of 1/4 * Million stronger than noise.

## The signal power (per my assumptions) is 250,000X more powerful than the noise

power.

This is an SNR of 60 -3 -3 = 54dB SNR. With assumed system bandwidth of 1/100th second, the correlation time.

Why is this possible? fundamentally your own neural patterns (firings) are a correlator, a "matched filter" ( another phrase to lay on the Venture Capitalists) with 100 seconds correlation_window.

Comment: Thank you so much for posting!  Can you take a look at my comment under the question and shoot me an email?  I was wondering if we can chat about this?  This video says there is an eight feet electromagnetic field, but I think it's larger.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p4SYv95cP68&list=PL8cY8dl9U5_HjD3nY5VsC3AXzc4H7W3oc&index=1

Comment: This is great!  I hope the question doesn't get closed because it would be a tragedy to lose this answer.

Comment: Kirlian photography is a method used to measure this.

Comment: [Kirlian photography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirlian_photography) is a thing, and it has its uses.  Detecting "auras" and "biofields" with Kirlian photography is [busted parapsychology bunk.](http://skepdic.com/kirlian.html)

Comment: @MacGyver:  Your video about the "eight foot electromagnetic field" is from the well known bullshit peddler [Deepak Chopra.](https://rationalwiki.org/wiki/Deepak_Chopra)  Get your information from reliable sources instead of bullshit artists.